# Show comments of certain merged cells in protected mode

Tags: excel, vba

I need to show comments in certain merged cells that are unlocked.

I found code online to show all comments in a workbook. This will not work because my workbook needs to be protected, which means the macro will look at locked cells and end prematurely.

```
Sub Show_Comment()
On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Set allCommentRng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
        For Each Rng In allCommentRng
            Rng.Comment.Visible = True
        Next
    Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

I need to know how to specify a merged range that has a comment. The first merged range is "C7:C8-E7:E8". If I know how to do one range, I will figure our how to do the others.

A picture of what the cell looks like as well as the button:

[image]

This not for school.

Answer (score 2):

You must first unprotect worksheet before trying to manipulate it and after changes have been applies, restore protection.

```
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      ws.Unprotect
      Set allCommentRng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
      For Each Rng In allCommentRng
          Rng.Comment.Visible = True
      Next Rng
      ws.Protect
  Next ws
```

Example above implies no password protection. To overcome password protection for worksheets use:

```
ws.Unprotect Password:="yourpasswordhere"
ws.Protect Password:="yourpasswordhere"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I need the workbook to the protected because I will be sharing this to someone else. However, I do not want them to be able to modify anything else in the workbook. They can only click the button and show the comments. I have made the button, the merged cells and the comment unlocked so that they are not impacted by protection. But I do not want the macro to look at any other section.

Comment: For the password part, is there a macro that can enter the password in the background? I have tried adding the password code but I am prompted to enter a password when the workbook is in protected mode. If someone else has this workbook, they will not have access to the password. Therefore, is there a macro that can input the password in the background when unprotecting and protecting the workbook? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

How about if you unprotect the worksheet before you run the macro and re-protect if after:

```
Sub Show_Comment()
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.unprotect
    Set allCommentRng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    For Each Rng In allCommentRng
        Rng.Comment.Visible = True
    Next Rng
    ws.protect
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.protect` is inside the range loop

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much :D

Comment: No problem, glad to help.